# Threading two functions inside a method of a class Python

Tags: python, multithreading, function, class, multiprocess

I want to run 2 functions inside a method of a class at the same time in Python. I tried to use `threading` module but it doesn't work. My example codes are as below:

```
import os, sys
import threading
from threading import Thread

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.method_1()

    def method_1(self):

        def run(self):
            threading.Thread(target = function_a(self)).start()
            threading.Thread(target = function_b(self)).start()

        def function_a(self):
            for i in range(10):
                print (1)

        def function_b(self):
            for i in range(10):
                print (2)

        run(self)


Example()
```

If above codes get executed, it will just print all `1`s first and then all `2`s. However, what I want is to print `1` and `2` at the same time. Thus, the desired output should be them mixed up.

Is `threading` module capable to do that? If not, what module can do that?  If anyone knows how to solve it, please let me know. Appreciated!!

Comment: Please specify what exactly you mean by "doesn't work"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the argument differently. Now you are actually executing your function in the `threading.Thread` initialisation call instead of creating a thread that executes the function.

If something needs a function as a parameter, always use just `function`. If you write `function()`, Python will not pass the actual function as a parameter, but executes the function on the spot and uses the return value instead.

```
def run(self):
    threading.Thread(target = function_a, args=(self,)).start()
    threading.Thread(target = function_b, args=(self,)).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
import os, sys
import threading
from threading import Thread
import time

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.method_1()

    def method_1(self):

        def run(self):
            threading.Thread(target = function_a, args = (self,)).start()
            threading.Thread(target = function_b, args = (self,)).start()

        def function_a(self):
            for i in range(10):
                print (1)
                time.sleep(0.01) # Add some delay here

        def function_b(self):
            for i in range(10):
                print (2)
                time.sleep(0.01) # and here


        run(self)


Example()
```

You will get outputs like this:

```
1
2
1
2
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
```

Comment: I do not think this answers the question, as the question was about doing everything inside a class instance instead of writing components out of it or creating new classes.

Comment: Looks like you have a point there, I will try to properly modify it.